# Minor issues with a Google API Project

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I'm encountering two problem with my Google API Project.

First, I've been working with this project for several weeks but the past couple days I have started seeing this error in my console.  Everything works fine, I just get this annoying message.

```
Unknown RPC service: _noop_echo       cb=gapi.loaded_0:71
```

Secondly, I get this new dialog that keeps fading in but I don't know how to disable it.  It appears for a couple seconds and then fades out.

[image]

I originally had the Google+ API turned on for my project but I turned it off since I only needed the Google Drive API and SDK.  I thought these problems may have started after turning the Google+ API off in my project but turning it back on has no effect.

Comment: Which language are you using? Give more details please.

Comment: Javascript, but I don't think it matters for the second issue. https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-client

Comment: The same thing happens for me. I'm using Google Drive with JavaScript and Dart. I think it's recent since it didn't happen on a previous project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out how to prevent the new "Welcome back" dialog from appearing.  I just  added the following line of code in my `handleAuthResult` function from the docs here.
https://developers.google.com/drive/auth/web-client

```
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    ...
    $("iframe").hide();
}
```

The "Welcome back" dialog is an iframe wrapped in a few divs.  The problem is the ID for the iframe appears to be randomly generated and there are no IDs used in the parent divs.  My project doesn't use any iframes so just hiding all iframes does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Google just fixed a bug. You should no longer see the message unless you are using the `plus.login` scope.

That message is intended for users that have signed in with Google+ Sign-In, but was appearing more often than designed.